# How to select all div's from the scraped HTML code of other website using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, parsing

I am developing a **chrome extension** and then I am calling an **XMLHttpRequest** to get the data from **another website** and store it in a variable to be parsed later using Jquery.

I got the entire html source code in the variable **parseText** variable.

The main problem is to find all the div's with a specific class name in the parseText variable and then loop it one after other and fill the data in the popup.html.

Can you assist me to parse the html data and to extract the div's using the specific class name?

My code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
        <title>Youtube Chrome Extenstion</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
          <h4>Hello Cricbuzz</h4>
          <div class="" id="y">

          </div>
        </div>


        <!-- Main functionality js  -->
        <!-- <script src="scripts/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script> -->

        <script src="scripts/loadapi.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

        <!-- Jquery Required for bootstrap -->
        <script src="scripts/jquery.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <!-- bootstrap Javascript -->
        <script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

LoadApi.js file code is here. Its main functionality is to get the data from the specific site and then store it in a variable.

```
console.log("Hello api call");

var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.cricbuzz.com/cricket-match/live-scores', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange= function() {
    if (this.readyState!==4) return;
    if (this.status!==200) return; // or whatever error handling you want
    //document.getElementById('y').innerHTML= this.responseText;
    //console.log(this.responseText);

    var $parseText = this.responseText;
    //console.log($parseText);
    //PROBLEM HERE HOW TO FIND ALL DIVS USING CLASS NAME BELOW
    $parseText.find(".cb-col.cb-col-100.cb-lv-main")

};
xhr.send();
```

**manifest.json**

```
"content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://www.cricbuzz.com/"],
        "js": ["scripts/jquery.js", "scripts/main.js"]
    }, {
        "matches": ["http://*/* " , "https://*/*"   ],
        "js": ["scripts/loadapi.js"]
    }],
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/icon_16.png",
        "48": "images/icon_48.png",
        "128": "images/icon_128.png"
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "images/icon_128.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

Expected Output:
[image]

Struck at this point:
[image]

Comment: Please state the problem - expected output versus actual output plus possible error messages from console

Comment: 1: you cannot just access another website unless it supports CORS. 2. You should use $.ajax instead of httpxmlrequest.

Comment: You should get the scores on the server: https://github.com/psibi/cricbuzz

Comment: try like this `var $parseText = $(this.responseText);` `var ele = $(".cb-col.cb-col-100.cb-lv-main",$parseText);`

Answer (score 0):

It's really not practical to get data like that but if you must

```
<script>
var uglyText  = "<div class='tofind'>good data</div><div class='noneed'>bad data</div><div class='tofind'>good data</div><div class='noneed'>bad data</div><div class='tofind'>good data</div><div class='noneed'>bad data</div>";

var lessThanUglyText = uglyText.split('<div'); // Split based on divs

var goodData = [];
var goodDataCount = 0;


for(var i = 0; i < lessThanUglyText.length; i++)
{
    if(lessThanUglyText[i].indexOf('tofind') == -1) // doesn't have class we want
    continue;
    goodData[goodDataCount] = lessThanUglyText[i].replace('</div>', ''); // trim the end
    goodDataCount++;    
}

for(var i = 0; i < goodData.length; i++)
{
    goodData[i] = goodData[i].substring(goodData[i].indexOf(">") + 1); // get what's inside the divs

}
</script>;
```

NOTE: This assumes that the class you are looking for cannot appear as normal text and that there are no nested divs inside each other as well as the absence of > inside data. A lot of constraints but this is a generic solution.

Comment: Can you please post a full div and what you want from it?